# Magento sending data from controller to view

Tags: magento-1.7

I am passing data from magento controller to view but my theme is not showing the content in the view is displayed in a white page
here is my code

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
->setData('products_notavailable',$Not_available_products)
->setData('products_available',$available_products)
->setData('quantity',$submit_qty)
->setTemplate('availableorders/display.phtml');
$this->renderLayout();
$this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
```

Comment: Please have a look in the [great debugging tutorial](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to insert the block, I assume you want to insert to content.

add this before render

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->insert($block);
```